# AutoSync is disabled in Android ICS LG P920 3D. How turn it on?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sync

After **upgrade Android from 2.3.x to 4.0.3** I can't turn on auto synchronization.
When Im trying I get msg:

```
AutoSync is disabled. Synchronization is enabled manually by server policy.
```

In **Settings -> Accounts & sync** have a disabled switcher as on the screens below.

Do you know how can I turn on auto sync?

Device model: **LG Optimus P920 3D.**
Android version: **4.0.4**
I'm abroad and using wifi and roaming GSM.

Screenshoots:

[image: Settings]

[image: Sync Settings]

Comment: Just to clearify: Are you talking about ActiveSync (MS Exchange), as the error message mentions a "server policy"? If not, which AutoSync do you refer to exactly?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to sync a MS Exchange account. I imagine the newer versions of Android correctly follow the policies set forth by the Exchange Server, and in this case the server admin has not allowed auto sync. The older version of Android likely didn't implement the proper security requests of the server, so you were able to have auto sync despite the Exchange admin having told the device not to do that. So now, you'll have to talk with your Exchange admin to ask them to enable this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for advice, problem was with MS Exchange.

I had to **delete MS Exchange account and recreate** after this Exchange asked me about permission for account and everything works fine.